# .htaccess редирект для https на другой robots.txt

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, редирект, mod-rewrite

Есть .htaccess, в котором в начале добавил следующее правило:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots-https.txt
```

Задумка такова, что необходимо для версии сайта с HTTPS отображать другой robots.txt по тому же самому URL. Но почему-то отображается старый. Пробовал варианты:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on 

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} on

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-HTTPS} 1

RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"https"'

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Protocol} https

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
```

Ни один не срабатывает... В чем может быть причина. Любые другие редиректы работают.

Сам .htaccess:

```
php_value allow_url_fopen On
php_value max_execution_time 100
php_value memory_limit 512M
php_flag log_errors on

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-HTTPS} 1
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"https"'
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Protocol} https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots-https.txt

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://%1/$0 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access 7 days"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 7 day"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 year"
</IfModule>


<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript
</ifModule>

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
    mod_gzip_on Yes
    mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
    mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
    mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Мне помог такой вариант, согласно инструкции REG.RU, на хостинге hc.ru

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots-https.txt
```

А вообще если возникают жесткие проблемы с редиректами, обычно помогает техподдержка хостинга.